# Bash CURL to PHP CURL translation

Tags: php, curl, mixpanel

I am having trouble translation the following query from a tutorial (Mixpanel JQL) written in bash, to a PHP Curl query:

**Bash code**

```
# sends the JQL code in `query.js` to the api
# to a project with sample data for this tutorial
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql \
    -u ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5: \
    --data-urlencode script@query.js | python -m json.tool
```

**Questions**

- In PHP, which CURL options should i use to do the equivalent;
- What would be the path to script (i'm guessing an accessible HTTP url?);
- What does `python -m json.tool` actually do and do I need it ?

Reference: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/jql/getting-started

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you removed your password, as -u is HTTP auth. The following example has *password* where you need to place it. (remove the stars though!).

python -m json.tool is what the curl command is being piped in to, it's a json formatter. So I assume your service is returning a json format.

I'm not sure what your file script@query.js is, so I assumed it's a filename. And thus added file_get_contents to it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5:*password*");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode(file_get_contents("script@query.js")));
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. The string USERPWD is actually an API key, so i'm not sure i need the password. Do you confirm ?

Comment: I figured it out, your anwser is not the correct one though it helped pointing to the correct script :-). Thanks !

Comment: Your example below is basically the same in a different notation; only curlopt_postfields should become array("script" => urlencode(scriptcontents)).

Comment: I just did bellow !

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked, the call to ba made is actuallty simple.

**Call**

Request URL (GET) `https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql?script=<javscript script contents>`

**In PHP**

```
$scriptContents = file_get_contents(<FILE PATH>);
$request_url = 'https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql?script='.urlencode($scriptContents);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => <Request URL>,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 2,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => 1,
    CURLAUTH_ANY => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5',
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```